# How to write a custom IMA policy for Apparmor

Tags: apparmor

I want to write a custom policy for IMA to validate all my apparmor profile files kept in /etc/apparmor folder. I couldnt figure out how to write a custom IMA policy to measure and appraise files from a particular folder. For SELinux, there is support to measure and fix based on a label. eg: appraise func=BPRM_CHECK subj_role=test
How to achieve the same for apparmor case?